# Problemas com Implementação de View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando utilizar o conceito de View Model Pattern, porém quando estou implementando o compilador está apresentando um erro de conversão.

Abaixo segue abordagem que utilizei:

Estrutura da viewmodel

```
public class EvolucaoViewModel
{
    public Chamado ChamadoAtual { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Evolucao> Evolucoes { get; set; }
}
```

Implementação no controller

```
public ActionResult DetalharChamado(int? id)
{
    EvolucaoViewModel model = new EvolucaoViewModel();

    model.ChamadoAtual = _contexto.Chamados.Find(id);
    model.Evolucoes = _contexto.Evolucoes.Where(e => e.id_chamado == id);

    ViewBag.id_usuario = new SelectList(_contexto.Usuarios, "id_usuario", "nome_usuario", model.ChamadoAtual.id_usuario).OrderBy(p => p.Text);
    ViewBag.id_chamado = id;
    ViewBag.id_setor = new SelectList(_contexto.Setores, "id_setor", "nome_setor", model.ChamadoAtual.id_setor);
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    if (model == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Quando tento fazer essa atribuição o VS me apresenta a mensagem abaixo:

```
model.Evolucoes = _contexto.Evolucoes.Where(e => e.id_chamado == id);
```

> Erro 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) E:\DevSpace\Projetos\Albasi.Atende\Albasi.Atende.Web\Controllers\ChamadoController.cs 77 31 Albasi.Atende.Web

O que preciso modificar?

Comment: Deu certo, jovem?

Comment: Olá jbueno, para o controller sim, porém para exibição na view só consegui por meio do helper Gridview. Não tem como eu utilizar HTMLHelper?

Comment: Marcelo, ótimo então. Mas eu não faço ideia sobre este novo problema. Aliás, ele deve ser resolvido em outra publicação, ok? Abra uma [nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) com sua dúvida atual, explicando o seu cenário e marque a resposta que mais te ajudou como correta usando o **✓** do lado esquerdo da resposta (você só pode marcar uma como correta).

Answer (score 3):

A propriedade `Evolucoes` da ViewModel declara uma `ICollection` e o retorno do método `Where` (ao menos quando aplicado a um `IQueryable`) é sempre um `IQueryable`, ou seja, você está tentando fazer um `ICollection` receber um `IQueryable`, isso está errado.

É preciso converter o retorno do `Where` para algum tipo que implemente `ICollection`, como `List` ou outros.

O que você precisa trocar é

Esta linha

```
model.Evolucoes = _contexto.Evolucoes.Where(e => e.id_chamado == id);
```

Para

```
model.Evolucoes = _contexto.Evolucoes.Where(e => e.id_chamado == id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a conversão para lista ".ToList()" no trecho abaixo:

```
model.Evolucoes = _contexto.Evolucoes.Where(e => e.id_chamado == id).ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado jbueno e Elton. Situação parcialmente resolvida... me deparei agora com uma nova situação, dessa vez na view. Lá não consegui utilizar HTMLHelpers para exibir as informações da coleção Evoluções. Só consegui fazê-lo utilizando uma WebGrid. Como poderia fazer para utilizar algo como @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Evolucoes.texto_evolucao) ???

Comment: Por que você simplesmente copiou a minha resposta, Elton?

Comment: @jbueno, provavelmente eu não vi a sua resposta. Note que ela é bem simples, apenas um "ToList" resolve o problema de cast e também o intervalo entre a minha e a sua publicação foi bem pequeno. ok?

Comment: Estranho, são 57 minutos de diferença, mas eu acredito em você. Perguntei mesmo porque as vezes o pessoal que chega novo acaba confundindo algumas coisas...

Comment: @jbueno, zelar por qualidade e cumprimento das regras é uma virtude! Parabéns pelo seu trabalho na comunidade. Se acha que a resposta é repedita, eu excluo numa boa! o que acha?

Comment: Nah, é uma linha de código só e a solução é realmente essa, faz sentido termos pensado na mesma coisa. Pode manter ela e, como tá certa, vou deixar um voto positivo.

Comment: @jbueno, deixei o meu voto no seu ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
model.ChamadoAtual = _contexto.Chamados.Include(i => i.Evolucoes).Find(id);
```

e remove o

```
model.Evolucoes = _contexto.Evolucoes.Where(e => e.id_chamado == id);
```

Comment: Tentando dessa forma o compilador apresenta o seguinte erro:
Erro 5 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Está faltando dar using System.Data.Entity; ou também dá para tentar:

    model.ChamadoAtual = _contexto.Chamados.Include("Evolucoes").Find(id);

Comment: Já estou utilizando o using System.Data.Entity; 

Com a modificação sugerida o compilador apresenta o seguinte erro:
Erro 4 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Albasi.Atende.Dominio.Entidades.Chamado>' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Albasi.Atende.Dominio.Entidades.Chamado>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)